# CsvReader - Tab delimiter data

Tags: c#, tabs, delimiter

I am working with CsvReader from https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader

Delimiter will be depend on type of data source, so my delimiter char stores in database.

It is working perfectly fine for Comma(,) and Pipe (|).

Now i got Tab separated values, and tab character is "\t" i.e. 2 character instead of 1 character which is expected by CsvReader.

So i changed data type of delimiter to Varchar(2), now while modifying it in C# throws error as "String must be exactly one character long"

Another option is to store Ascii value and convert to Char in C#.

Is there anything i can do with Escape character while converting string to char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string specified by the string literal "\t" is 1 character long.  It just takes two characters (actually four including the quotes) to specify in a string literal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

So how i can convert this to tab character in C# using Convert.ToChar function, I mean to Char data type.

Comment: The correct thing to do is to store it as a tab character in the database, rather than store it as a string with escape sequences and then try to "parse" it in C#.  I checked quickly, and it looks like SQL databases differ on how to specify characters.  For instance, it appears you specify a horizontal tab in SQL Server as char(9).

Comment: I specified in database as \t in database and checked with Char.Parse also but getting same exception i.e. String must be exactly one character long.

As i said, last option is to store ascii value :(

Comment: As I said in my last comment, you don't want to store a C# string literal in your database.  You want to store an actual tab character.  How to specify a tab character in SQL varies by database, but you'd want to do something like `insert into someschema.sometable values (char(9))`

Comment: I think "correct" here might depend on use case needs.  Personally I find having special chars that I can't "see" in my database annoying--but I work on my databases quite a bit directly using DBA tools.  adv12's solution is definitely more efficient.

Comment: Yes, it worked, 
BTW, if we look at database value, it just show blank value

Anyhow, it worked, thanks

Comment: @scotru, putting C# string literals into a database makes the database only readable by systems that use the same conventions for string literals as C#.  If you can't guarantee that the database will never be read by a system (or person) that doesn't know and assume C#'s rules for string parsing, then it's best not to store C# string literals in it.

Comment: @adv12 Agreed.  It just depends on the use case.  Like using markdown in a database field or any other string formatting convention.

Answer (score 0):

An escaped value is still a single char long.  You can write to assign a tab character (ASCII 9) to a char variable:

```
        char value = '\t';
```

If you need to convert an escaped string read from your database, you could just replace the \t value with the actual value, ie:

```
        string newstring = mystring.Replace("\\t", "\t");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

So in this case, i am getting this as Varchar(2) from database i.e. string in C#, now how to convert it to Char data type from string, i am getting error during conversion

Comment: You could use mystring.Replace("\\t","\t")